# Using fseek and fwrite to overwrite a line in a file

Tags: c, fwrite, fseek

I have a text file where each line is terminated by a "\n". Like so

```
0000
0000
0000
0000
```

Now, a file initially starts like above but a line can be overwritten with another line of variable length. I am using `fseek()` in order to set the position indicator of the stream. I have no problems moving to a line and replacing for example `0000` with `1111`.

Now lets say I want to replace the first line with `1111 1111`. I do the following

```
char *str = "1111 1111\n";
fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), file);
```

This deletes line 2 and 1 byte from line 3 like so

```
1111 1111
000
0000
```

What is the cause of this?

Comment: This will never compile, `fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), FILE);` is likely wrong.

Comment: @iharob This compiles.

Comment: Are you sure it's `FILE`? that's the name of a type.

Comment: It's a file.  You cannot arbitrarily shove extra stuff into the middle of it.  If you want to extend a line of text than you will need to copy the whole file.

Comment: @iharob Ah, sorry I see what you mean. I just left my caps key on. In my code it's a variable `file`

Comment: Do not type the code into the editor of SO, copy and paste it.

Comment: one possibility.  if the line endings in the file are not windows/dos and the compiler is translating '\n' to a windows/dos two char line ending sequence

Comment: for good programing practice, local variables should not be the same as C types, with only the capitalization changed.

Comment: look at the resulting file with a hex text editor to see what is actually occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of your file like:
"0000\n0000\n0000\n0000\n"

It will be easier to understand that when you overwrite first line you are overwriting first n-number of chars really. 
So that is why your second line disappears.

Comment: I wonder why '1111  1111\n' takes out the first zero of the third line?

Comment: It's probably outputting "1111 1111\r\n" over the top of "1111\n1111\n0". Opening the file in binary mode (FILE *file = fopen(fname, "rb+");) should fix that...